# Open source API/SDK for mobile app like webrtc

Tags: android, ios, webrtc

Which open source API/SDK used to create an app just like zoom or gotomeeting. In which I used (video chat, audio chat, text chat and screen sharing)?

Comment: Webrtc **is** an open source API for video chat, audio chat and screen sharing........

Comment: Kevin, I read about Webrtc that supports only web browser but I am looking for an open source SDK that supports same functionality in mobile.

Comment: You read wrong. Webrtc has a native API and a javascript implementation. [Read more here](http://www.webrtc.org/)

Comment: Thanks Kevin for sharing that link.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try below SDK hope it will help you

Click on below link and download android SDK

[Open Peer SDK](http://openpeer.org/open-peer-sdk-for-android/)

Comment: Thanks @AndroidWebLineindia

Comment: If it work for you then please accept / upvote the answer, it might be helpful for others too.

Comment: Currently, i am implementing that in iOS and android, Once i succeed I upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is few open source but every one of those have some issue.

Simplewebrtc www.simplewebrtc.com 
Don't have android SDK. but its good in web and ios.

Easyrtc www.easyrtc.com
Web is free but they charge for ios  and android SDK.

Openpeer www.openpeer.org
This is quite good they have all ios, android and web api.